# Apache Kafka why producer is connected by broker, but consumer is connected to zookeeper？

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

The old version suggests that consumer connect zookeeper, and the new version suggests linking broker? A netizen from a community replied to me that the old version of topic's offset is ZK, and the new version is Kafka itself. Is this the answer to this answer?

Answer (score 4):

Older versions of Kafka i.e before 0.9 version store offsets with Zookeeper.

Newer version of Kafka, store offsets in an internal Kafka topic called **__consumer_offsets**.

The newer version still provides the feasibility to store offsets with Zookeeeper.

With this the consumers can now only talk to the Brokers and does not need to rely on Zookeeper.

If there are many consumers simultaneously reading from Kafka, the read write load on ZooKeeper may exceed its capacity, making ZooKeeper a bottleneck.

check this for more information

https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/502